# unrecognized selector sent to class 0x865c6c

Tags: ios, objective-c, zbar-sdk, zbar

While am trying to integrate Zbar sdk to am getting this error.

```
"+[QRCodeReadViewController presentViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x865c74";
```

Thanks in advance

My code is

```
    +(void)startfn{

        ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
        reader.readerDelegate =self;
        ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

        [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                       config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                           to: 0];

          [self presentViewController:reader animated:NO];
    [reader release];
}
```

Comment: add  ZBarSDK framework and import it in that file.http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/tutorial.html

Comment: The proper method to call is `-[QRCodeReadViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]`.

Comment: have u imported the zbar sdk?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `startfn` a class method? In that case `self` refers to the class `QRCodeReadViewController` and not to an instance of that class, so you can't call `presentViewController:animated:completion:` which is a method of `UIViewController`'s instances.